# PHP Illegal String Offset - But Array is Set

Tags: php, arrays, json

Maybe a trivial Problem - but im stuck. I have an Array, printed out with print_r

```
Array ( [Code] => 200 [Content] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [BelegID] => XXXX [BelegDatum] => 1453330800 [Lager] => ABCLAGER [Transporteur] => 0 ) ) )
```

When i try to access the Array via

```
if($auftrag['Code'] == "200"){DO SOMETHING}
```

I get the error

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Code' in
```

Can someone enlight me please?

Cheers

Comment: `$auftrag` must be a string and not an array.

Comment: maybe a typo in array definition? double-check.

Comment: How can i Change that? That it is an array

Comment: No, if you have this error. check -it via print_r **precisely** before `if` loop, pasting `$auftrag` from the `if`. I think a typo or a different scope variable. (Edit: no different scope. It's a string).

Comment: Somewhere before that line you may have reassigned a string to `$auftrag`.

Comment: Your question is off-topic because it doesn't even contain example code for reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found my error. It was human working overtime mistake.

I was only doing print_r the Array - so it printed out properly. But i wasn t saving the result of json decode to $auftrag.